# replacing the TH after #'s in a cell

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Alright so I have been using Regex until now to take care of a little clean up in a directory file. The problem I am having now is that the code I would use replaces the whole pattern.

```
Function CorrectTH(r As String) As String
 With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "[0-9]+TH\b"
    CorrectTH = .Replace(r, "th")
 End With
End Function
```

If I come across something like

"9TH ave & Hill St"

my replace will give me back

"th ave & Hill St"

when obviously I want to keep any numbers before the th. In this instance I want to return

"9th ave & Hill St"

Any trick to just change some of the pattern?

Comment: `.Pattern = "([0-9]+)TH\b"` and then `CorrectTH = .Replace(r, "$1th")`

Comment: It is also worth looking at [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300.aspx).  It's not great, but at least has an example that points in the right direction.